Firebase-Admin Sdk-Invite User To Sign Up With Email And Password
In my application i allow super admin users to invite other members to signUp with email and password, so i follow this steps, first after admin user invite member, i generate sign in action link with user email in the continue url parameters then insert it into the custom sign-up email and then emailed to the corresponding user. then after user click on action link i will validate in client side using firbase method that take action link and user email, and if succeed then i will send request update profile to my backend side using generated ID token.
but i found in firebase documentation recommendation
Do not pass the user’s email in the redirect URL parameters and re-use it as this may enable session injections.
so what is the other alternative could i use in my sign up follow
